# ntlm and wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ntlm

I ask you to provide me with information on the operation of the ntlm protocol through the wso2 api manager.
We are planning to use the wso2 api manager 3.2 product with the purchase of technical support. But for now, we are collecting information about the capabilities of the product. We have endpoints, their authorization works with the ntlm protocol. We are interested in whether the ntlm mechanism will work through wso2 api manager 3.2? Is this a working circuit?
We also ask because our colleagues are having difficulties with such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WSO2 APIM-3.2.0 supports NTLM grant type. You can obtain an access token to your API in an API Manager instance running on Windows by providing a valid NTLM token as an authorization grant. You can find the complete guide on NTLM support in WSO2 APIM-3.2.0 via https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/ntlm-grant/

Comment: I am afraid that the link you provided says a little differently. As far as I understand, this article is about protecting a newly created API using ntlm.
I am concerned about something else. I cannot log in to the destination server, which is located at the address published in the endpoint.
If I try to authorize using a direct link, then everything works. If I log in by sending a request via wso2, then the final server swears at an authorization error.

Comment: Can you please tell me, is it real to transfer ntlm credentials through the wso2 api manager for the final service that is specified in the endpoint?